# activemq transactional support

Tags: transactions, activemq-classic

I am trying to develop a multi-threaded activemq consumer.
The messages get processed in multiple threads.
Is it possible to rollback message for a particular thread in case of some exception or failure?
I am looking into session.rollback() and session.commit() but if i call these methods how will i make sure  that a particular message gets rolled back?

I am also open if i can selectively commit some message.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Aeijit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on where your transaction boundaries are set.  generally, each thread will have its own transaction and will commit/rollback all messages in its transaction.

another option is to just use the general exception/retry/DLQ strategies to handle individual message failures, this is easier and meets most requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can either manage message acknowledgement yourself by using Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE and rollback and commit, or preferably [make use of a transaction manager](http://www.jakubkorab.net/2011/08/configuring-activemq-transactions-in-spring.html) to handle this behaviour for you. You should take a look at [message redelivery and dead-letter queue handling](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) to get a sense of the options available to you for handling rolled back messages.